# How do you get a specific item in an enumeration by a variable integer in c#?

Tags: c#, enums

I have this enumeration list

```
enum Month
{
    January = 1,
    February,
    March,
    April,
    May,
    June,
    July,
    August,
    September,
    October,
    November,
    December
}
```

I am gathering an integer from the console named input with a value of 1-12. How do I make it print out the corresponding month? Eg:1 = January, 6=June.

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the `int` to your Enum

```
var m = (Month)1;

Console.WriteLine(m.ToString());
```

But bear in mind if the enum value isn't defined it will simply print the int.

Alternatively you can use

```
var m = Enum.GetName(typeof(Month), 1);
```

which will return `null` if it isn't defined

Answer (score 0):

I invite you to read the documentation about [enums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum)

And here is the answer to your question :

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
int enumIntValue = int.Parse(input); // You can also use TryParse (safer).
Month month = (Month) enumIntValue; // You can use Enum.IsDefined before to check if the int value is valid for the enum. 
Console.WriteLine(month); // print out the month.
```

Read also :
[TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0), [Enum.IsDefined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

For information purposes, to see all of the textual values in an enum, you can get the values like so ...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Month));

    foreach (var enumValue in enumValues)
        Console.WriteLine(enumValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the integer value to the corresponding Enum via a cast, and then get its string representation:

```cs
var monthEnum = (Month)yourIntValue;
var strEnum = monthEnum.ToString();
```

Note that if `yourIntValue` isn't a valid enum value (e.g. 0, or 13), then the program will still run, but will output the integer value.

Also note that a better way to get a month's name would be to use the [`CultureInfo` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-6.0):

```cs
// the current culture info, from your computer
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture; 

// you can also specify a known culture 
culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en")
var monthName = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(yourIntValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input= Console.ReadLine();
Month month = 0;
if (Enum.TryParse(input, out month)) //Using try parse is safer
{
Console.WriteLine(month.ToString());
}
```